# jQuery plugin to filter result from a select drop down box

Tags: jquery

Here is one jQuery plugins which allow me to filter the result of drop down values. I am looking for a plugin which allows user to type right there in the drop down box and it filters records. Anyone knows of such plugin.

In that plugin dropdown box displays all the choices. User can go and pick a value or user can filter the result by typing something.

http://nihilex.com/droplist-filter

Update:

Looks I found what I was looking for. Here is the [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SexyCombo) and here is the [demo](http://phone.witamean.net/sexy-combo/examples/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you best solution is to use something like [jquery's autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete). Then do some custom validation to make sure that you only accept input from what's available in autocomplete selections.

Essentially, you would replace your `<select/>`s with `<input type="text"/>`s.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are looking for something like this: http://phone.witamean.net/sexy-combo/

This allow the same behavior of a select list but you are also able to type and filter the options.  You can view the demo page here: http://phone.witamean.net/sexy-combo/examples/index.html

Comment: Sorry, I am not the original owner and can't provide a new link.  It looks like http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SexyCombo is where the plugin exists.